# For loop assign a variable name for each loop iteration

Tags: python

This is a part of a code I've been working on, during the `for` loop it iterates through `product_buttons` in order to define which button is selected, and after a button is selected I wanted to show which button was selected and I have managed to do it as follows:

product_buttons = [36,38,40] #raspberry pi pins

```
in_progress = False
ended = True
product = None

def show_msg(wid,msg):
    wid.config(text = msg)
    pass

def button_loop():
    global in_progress,ended
    waiting = False
    product = None
    while True:
        for i in range(len(product_buttons)):
            button = IO.input(product_buttons[i])
            if button:
                print(i,in_progress,ended,product)
                if not in_progress:
                    product = i
                    while not ended:
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                    in_progress = True
                    show_msg(root.lab_quality,'Button {}
```

pressed'.format(i))

The code works fine and whenever a button is pressed it changes `Button {} pressed` with Button 0 pressed, Button 1 pressed or Button 2 pressed.
Now what I was trying to do was to assign a variable name to each iteration in the `for` loop in order to achieve something like:

`i = 0` make i = to a variable for example let's call it a
`i = 1` make i = to b
`i = 2` make i = to c

So that (still for example) when button 0 is pressed it shows Button a is pressed.
I have tried to store the values like this `quality={1:a, 2:b, 3:c}` and then call it with `show_msg(root.lab_quality,'Button {} pressed'.format(quality))`, this was the idea I had in mind but didn't work out and I am a bit stuck and I need to be pointed in the right direction so that I can eventually work it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't try to use separate variables.  Store them in a list instead.  You can then refer to `btn[0]` or `btn[1]`, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys I have worked it out I did:

```
btn = ['a','b','c']
show_msg(root.lab_quality,'QUALITY {}'.format(btn[j]))
```

and works like a charm, was so easy I don't know why I didn't see it before.

Comment: In StackOverflow regulations, you need to avoid using like `Thanks`. Instead, you have to vote on the helpful answers and comments and select the answer that works for you as the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `quality` as a dictionary like this: `quality={'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c'}`. Then, you can call `show_msg` function:

```
show_msg(root.lab_quality,'Button {} pressed'.format(quality[str(i)]))
```

This way you use the value of `i` variable as the key to read its name from the quality dictionary.

Comment: @matteo Have you also tried this solution? This solution does not have the limitation that you have in list indices.